# changeing only pixels that are predominantly red, rather than removing the red component of all pixels

Tags: python-3.x

Please I want to change only pixels that are  predominantly red, rather than removing the red component of all pixels. (I am using python 3.5) What might be wrong with my code.

```
from cImage import *
def removeRed(imageFile):
    myimagewindow = ImageWin("Image Processing",1000,500)   
    oldimage = FileImage(imageFile)
    oldimage.draw(myimagewindow)

    width = oldimage.getWidth()
    height = oldimage.getHeight()
    newim = EmptyImage(width,height)       

    for col in range(width):
        for row in range(height):
            old_pixel = oldimage.getPixel(col,row)
            new_pixel = Pixel(0, old_pixel.getGreen(), old_pixel.getBlue())
            newim.setPixel(col, row, new_pixel)
    newim.setPosition(width+1,0)
    newim.draw(myimagewindow)
    myimagewindow.exitOnClick()
removeRed("red.gif")
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I want to change only pixels that are predominantly red, rather than removing the red component of all pixels.

Comment: What do you want to replace your red pixels with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you define "predominant" by "highest value of R,G,B is R" then just compare values and set to 0 only if red is higher than both green and blue:

```
for col in range(width):
    for row in range(height):
        old_pixel = oldimage.getPixel(col,row)
        if old_pixel.getRed() > old_pixel.getGreen() and old_pixel.getRed() > old_pixel.getBlue():
            new_pixel = Pixel(0, old_pixel.getGreen(), old_pixel.getBlue())
            newim.setPixel(col, row, new_pixel)
        else:
            newim.setPixel(col, row, old_pixel)
```

Comment: For example I have a picture of a rose flower with a white background. This being the case, I would like to remove the red color from the rose flower without doing any other change to any color present in the picture. In short, I want the red color gone.

Comment: Predominant, in the sense that there is a part of the picture in red, so I want to remove that part alone,but because the background of the picture is white and there is a bit of red color in white, the background changes to cyan.In short I want to remove the red color from that specific pixel than removing it from the whole pixel

Comment: Have you tested my answer?

Comment: not working like what? I have tested it and if R is > B and > G, it removes the R component from the pixel.